# Upper Bound for discrete objective value

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, optimization, discrete-optimization

I really need your help with the following problem:
Let $ N \ge 3 $ be given, then consider
$$ L(N)=\max\left\lbrace \sum_{j=2}^{N-1} \frac{c_j}{j} \, \middle| \, c_j \in \mathbb{N}, \nexists 0\le d \le c: 1 \le  \sum_{j=2}^{N-1} \frac{d_j}{j}\le 1+\frac{1}{N} \right\rbrace. $$

Prove that $ L(K^2)\le K $ for all $ K\ge 2 $.

Comment: I have checked this by hand for $ K \in \lbrace 2,3,4 \rbrace $, but I cannot find a general proof. There are also some reduction methods:
(1) $ c_j \le j-1 $ can be set for all prime numbers $ j $
(2) $ c_j \le t(j)-1 $ can be set if $ t(j) $ denotes the smallest non-trivial divisor of $ j $